# Google Map in Umbraco not displaying

Tags: google-maps, umbraco

I have been trying to add google map to my Umbraco based website. It is only displaying longitude and latitude. I have tried going on google and searching for it, i have followed the instructions given by Lee but in vain. Please advice.

I can search the post code and choose the location, but the image is not displayed.

Comment: You will have to post some code (XSLT or otherwise) for us to see what the problem might be. However, this is unlikely to have anything to do with Umbraco. Also, who is Lee?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me on this.  I have managed to display the map on home page, the issue was the div tag. however, i cannot get it right on the text pages, which is inheriting from master page like home page. I believe it is the conflict in jqueries, but i cannot really tell which query is conflicting.  pls see the code below:'code'

Comment: I believe its jquery1.6.2 let me know how can i paste code here as it is not working, i have been trying to paste it for past half an hour. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for your help. I managed to solve it myself, it was not called recursvively, after calling it recursively , it worked on text pages too which was